Why can I create an array of user input size without dynamic allocation?
It's my understanding that in order to create an array of size determined at runtime, you need to use the "new" keyword to allocate the memory. However, I have created a snippet of code which compiles and runs as expected without it.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int size;
    std::cout << "How many students are in your class: ";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::string students[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        std::string place_holder;
        std::cout << "Input a student: ";
        std::cin >> place_holder;
        students[i] = place_holder;
    }
    std::cout << "Your students are ";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        std::cout << students[i];
        if(i < size-1){
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }  
    std::cout <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Why is this allowed? I have used both g++ and clang++ to compile the code and it runs fine with both. I have also tried compiling without optimizations.

Well, msvc doesn't support it

This is gcc/clang extension, not standard c++, see dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Because std::string students[size]; is NOT standard C++. But C++ has a standard solution. Use std::vector which is C++ resizable array type. You can just keep adding students with it's push_back method.

And your understanding of new/delete is correct. However in current C++ it is hardly used anymore. Becuase you can either store objects in a container, like std::vector. Or you have to use std::make_unique.  C++ core guidelines R.11 avoid calling new/delete explicitly. The reason is that untold memory leaks (or use after free) bugs are very common when you try to do memory managment all by yourself.

I have used both g++ and clang++ to compile the code and it runs fine with both -- Doesn't compile using the right compiler options.  You should compile with --pedantic-errors to see the issue.

The compiler should have issued a diagnostic, typically a warning, because the code does not conform to the language definition.
